# How to use forever-node with sudo command?

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, sudo, forever

I have a server of flash-cross-domain-policy wrote in Java script node.js:

```
var net = require("net");

var flashPolicyServer = net.createServer(function (stream) {
  stream.setTimeout(0);
  stream.setEncoding("utf8");

  stream.addListener("connect", function () {   
  });

  stream.addListener("data", function (data) {
    if ( data.indexOf('<policy-file-request/>') != -1){
                stream.write('<cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" /></cross-domain-policy>');
    } 
    stream.end();
  });

  stream.addListener("end", function() {
    stream.end();
  });
});

flashPolicyServer.listen(843);
```

I believe the port 843 must be of a special kind because I can only run this server using sudo node server.js. It is running beautifully. But I need to run it through the module forever to become more reliable.

How to execute it.. Eg. `sudo forever start server.js` ?

Comment: Yes, 843 is < 1024 and therefore is a privileged port that can be opened only by processes running with root privilege.  You should start it in an `init.d` script that runs at system boot time.  This is off-topic for SO, and probably belongs on [sf].

Answer (score 1):

```
forever start -c 'sudo node' server.js
```

Worked for me as an npm script when using forever installed locally instead of globally (npm install -g).

Answer (score 0):

`sudo forever start server.js` should work.

Alternatively,

```
>>> sudo su
>>> cd /folder/of/script
>>> forever start server.js
```

Comment: Be aware that running forever using sudo and running forever as the super user (sudo su) will yield different results as forever will store the pids in different home directories. Try running "forever config" as both sudo and superuser (sudo su) to see the difference in the config.